# Can I install the Worklight mobile browser simulator on Worklight Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-mbs

When i preview an Android App on Worklight server it still previews as a  "common" resource.
Whereas if i do the same on my local machine from eclipse it opens in a Mobile Browser simulator.

What is the way to install the mobile browser simulator on the server as well. My Worklight server is running on a Linux machine with WAS stand alone and DB2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MBS is part of the Worklight Development Server (Worklight Studio plug-in for Eclipse) and is meant for development-time only. 
The MBS is NOT available in a production environment.

By the time you deploy your .wlapp to your production Worklight Server, you should have already tested your app in the MBS, emulators and actual devices, again, prior to deployment.

The Worklight Console (where the MBS is available at during development) in a production environment is meant less for testing your app and more to managing it - push notifications, remote disable/notify, authenticity check enablement, analytics, etc.